# Generating specific y-axis in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to generate a y-axis like shown in the below plot in Python. I guess using matplotlib should help, but i cant figure out the code needed for that.

[image]

Comment: You can use ticks on the y axis

Comment: Hi Achilles. How exactly do I do this?

Comment: Could you show the values of your Y axis?

Comment: Ok Let me show you an example which will help you.

Comment: 99,99990134
99,99901344
99,99765819
99,99359183
99,99023872
99,98895495
99,98977619
99,99276222
99,99480763

Answer (score 1):

You need a logarithmic scale but this usually starts from zero. So the trick is to plot (1 - y) instead of y. Then you set the ticks and their labels. My suggestion (the values are < 1, but you can easily scale to 100):

```
# Some data
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([0.99, 0.999, 0.9923, 0.995, 0.997])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot the inverted data with log scale
ax.plot(x, 1 - y)
ax.set_ylim(0.1, 0.001)
ax.set_yscale("log")

# Now set what ticks (in transformed y) and what labels to use
ticks = np.array([0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1])
tick_labels = (1 - ticks) * 100

ax.set_yticks(ticks)
ax.set_yticklabels(tick_labels)
ax.set_ylabel("Some value in %")
# And you're done :-)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say for example you have a list for your y axis:

```
y = [1,2,3,4]
```

You can add ticks on it like this:

```
plt.yticks([90.0,99.0,99.9,99.99])
```

Thus changing the y axis label.